# Encode Url in PHP Problems in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, urlencode

I think this is an easy thing, but before I've tried to find a solution for almost one an hour.

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/quote?quote=<?php echo urlencode(the_permalink()) ?>&source=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()) ?>" title="Share On Tumblr">
```

Results are not yet encoded url:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share/quote?quote=http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/&source=how to make a cheat
```

Because it failed so I tried the code like this:

```
<?php
$linksf = the_permalink();
echo $linksf;
$linksf = urlencode($linksf);
echo $linksf;
$linksf = urlencode('http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/');
echo $linksf;
?>
```

The result is:

```
> http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/
> http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/
> http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fhow-to-make-cheat%2F
```

I want result like this:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share/quote?quote=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fhow-to-make-cheat%2F&source=how+to+make+a+cheat
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) instead. `the_permalink()` will echo the variable, not return it.

```
$linksf = urlencode( get_permalink() );
echo $linksf;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function the_permalink() {
    return 'http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/&source=how to make a cheat';
}

echo urlencode(the_permalink());
```

The result is

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fhow-to-make-cheat%2F%26source%3Dhow+to+make+a+cheat
```

I don't know why you got different results. You can test php code here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: so when I try to print (the_permalink ()); and 
print (urlencode (the_permalink ())); 
there is no difference in the results.
both have result like this http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the result of this code please ?

```
<?php var_dump(the_permalink()); ?>
```

I have the same thing than Phoenix when i'm testing your code with a function that returns

```
http://localhost/wp/how-to-make-cheat/&source=how to make a cheat
```

var_dump() will give you exactly what is returned by the_permalink() function ^^

Comment: mmhh... it should work properly, i don't understand ... maybe try with [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: i cant answer my own question..
Solved-
echo urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
echo urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_permalink(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));

Comment: ahhhh ahahha good job dude! Actually your browser displays only the final result ^ ^